# Spark always using an existing SparkContext every time i run job with spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I have deployed the jar of spark on cluster. I submit the spark job using `spark-submit` command follow by my project jar.

I have many `Spak Conf` in my project. Conf will be decided based on which class i am running but every time i run the spark job i got this warning

> 7/01/09 07:32:51 WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some
>   configuration may not take effect.

**Query** Does it mean SparkContext is already there and my job is picking this. 
**Query** Why come configurations are not taking place

Code

```
private val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("ELSSIE_Ingest_Cassandra")
    .setMaster(sparkIp)
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "8")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraIp)
    .set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")


object SparkJob extends Enumeration {

  val Program1, Program2, Program3, Program4, Program5 = Value
}

object ElssieCoreContext {

def getSparkSession(sparkJob: SparkJob.Value = SparkJob.RnfIngest): SparkSession = {
     val sparkSession = sparkJob match {
          case SparkJob.Program1 => {
            val updatedConf = conf.set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "2048").set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "2000")
            SparkSession.builder().config(updatedConf).getOrCreate()
          }
          case SparkJob.Program2 => {
            val updatedConf = conf.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "2000")
            SparkSession.builder().config(updatedConf).getOrCreate()
          }
    }
```

}

And In Program1.scala i call by

> ```
> val spark = ElssieCoreContext.getSparkSession()
> val sc = spark.sparkContext
> ```

Comment: @AkashSethi If it is in your hands, you can switch to create SparkContext directly from SparkConf and then use it everywhere else. Because it does not calls getOrCreate and hence it might solve you issue. !

Comment: but the problem is i need diffrent configuration for sparkSession as for cassandra i need diffrent conf and fir pipeline i need difert